# Animate the width of a block element as it changes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a block element that changes its width depending on what state its in.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/7/) to show you what I mean.

When the black button is clicked, you'll see that the text changes within that button which decreases the overall width. I'm wondering if there is a way either through CSS or JS that I can get the width to smoothly animate when the button is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>

<div id="primary"></div>
<div id="contact-keebs"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact-button {
    background: #000;
    background-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#primary {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
#contact-keebs {
    background: blue;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var c = 0;
$('#contact-button').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

        $(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');
        $('body').addClass('contact-content');
        $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeIn(500);

    } else {

        $(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');
        $('body').removeClass('contact-content');
        $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeOut(500);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `transition` to animate the `width`.

```js
var c = 0;
$('#contact-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (c++ % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work');
    $('body').addClass('contact-content');
    $('#contact-button').css('width', '30px');
    $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch');
    $('#contact-button').css('width', '85px');
    $('body').removeClass('contact-content');
    $('#contact-keebs').finish().stop().fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

```css
#contact-button {
  background: #000;
  background-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 85px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(.09,1.31,1,1.28);
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#primary {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
#contact-keebs {
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
<div id="primary"></div>
<div id="contact-keebs"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear in my post. I'm trying to get the black button's width to animate. The button changes width depending on what text is inside of it ('work', 'get in touch') and I want the width to smoothly animate. The other boxes (red, blue) are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS on #contact-button

Transition: width 2s linear;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can do it using CSS transitions and specifying a width (that's the bad part). Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/12/

The code for that is really simple, in the CSS you would just add this to the `#contact-button` styling:

```
overflow:hidden;
width:150px;
height:18px;
transition: width 0.5s linear;
-webkit-transition:width 0.5s linear;
```

(and some of them like the `height` or the `overflow` aren't really required)

Then in the JS, you specify the `width` of the box before/after changing the text content:

```
$(this).addClass('work-button').text('Work').css({width:"70px"})
...
$(this).removeClass('work-button').text('Get in touch').css({width:"140px"});
```

Then click on the button and look it grow/shrink.

Comment: You can add some additional styling (`white-space: nowrap;`) so the content doesn't break into two lines: http://jsfiddle.net/ddac5391/14/